# source activate does not activate python venv environment

Tags: python, pyvenv

I am using python 3.10, and create a virtual environment using

```
python -m venv .venv
```

seems bin folder generated in proper way, however when I use

`source .venv/bin/activate`

(venv) not showing up

tried:

1. export $PATH='usr/local/python3.10/bin'
2. create virtual environment using pycharm / vs code
3. /usr/local/python3.10 -m venv .venv
4. It's not zsh profile settings issue  as well the, zshrc setting doesn't work for me
   none of above solved the problem

Comment: Why are you writing `source` twice?

Comment: It sounds like you have a file named `source` and you're sourcing *that*, not the venv activation script.

Comment: Make sense, twice source are typo, fixed. You've gave me a hint. I will check how to solve.

Comment: finally, solved by it's IDE issue. vs Code didn't point interpret properly, switched into pycharm and point into python 3.10, then all solved. Thanks mate.